# Doesn't load content when initialize page ajax jquery

Tags: ajax

When I initialize mi website I want to load content of a file txt. But this doesn't load.

I made...

```
$("ul li a#start").on('load', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "pages/conoceGranada.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

But that doesn't work

Mi file git is in https://github.com/Mangulomx/web

Comment: try on document.ready

Comment: Thanks i try and work!

Comment: okey i added it as answer  mark it as correct answer and  mark question  as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "pages/conoceGranada.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

here is the solution